# Firebase Access permission make public (iOS Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, permissions, firebase-realtime-database

When I want to write data in Firebase so me error Like

> permission_denied

Please see Snap for Exject Idea.

[image]

I am Trying below **Code** -

```
private var _test_Kush = Firebase(url: "https://xxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/")

var test_Kush: Firebase {
   return _test_Kush
}

func testKushAdd(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
   test_Kush.childByAppendingPath(uid).setValue(user)
}
```

Comment: have you authenticated  before writing data

Comment: if you want to read / write data without authentication you'll have change rules of firebase database

Comment: how can I authenticate?

Comment: can you share one demo?
I am new in Swift and Firebase.
Thanks

Comment: you're login user with firebase auth?

Comment: I have not exjetly idea how can i use auth.

Comment: here is the documentation for auth [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)

Comment: Use of unresloved indentifire FIRAuth.
can we connect over skype or Teamviewer?
that would grate help for me.

Comment: I am Struct there.

Answer (score 2):

To make data public change firebase database rules :

Select **Database** then change the rules :

[image]

> Note: This is not the best way to approach you must use firebase
>   authentication to access database.
>   [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) is a
>   good documentation for auth and database.

Comment: Still not, Please help

Comment: You will not get permission_denied by using this

Comment: if you want to use auth just follow their documentation

Comment: Got It Now I can Add Data. If I need any help. I will connect. Thanks

Comment: @HamzaAnsari This way authenticated users will get permission denied. Instead you can just set it to true.